# How to find the extrema of a function?

Tags: optimization

I'm having problems finding the extrema of the function $h(x, y) = 2x sin(y) + y^2−x^2$. There is supposed to be one saddle point but I can't seem to get that. I tried taking $f_{xx}f_{yy} - f_{xy}^2$, but I can't seem to end up with 0. Anyone knows how to solve this problem? Would really appreciate it!

Comment: Did you calculate the gradient ?

Comment: I found $h_x = 2siny - 2x$ and $h_y = 2xcosy + 2y$

Comment: This is correct. They both must be $0$. So, $x=siny$ and $x=\frac{-y}{cos(y)}$

Comment: Did you check, if the origin is a saddle point ?